# How to Iterate through arrays in C?

Tags: arrays

So I need to fill in the code for the program to work for the question:

Array testGrades contains `NUM_VALS` test scores. Write a for loop that sets `sumExtra` to the total extra credit received. Full credit is 100, so anything over 100 is extra credit. Ex: If `testGrades = {101, 83, 107, 90}`, then `sumExtra = 8`, because 1 + 0 + 7 + 0 is 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int NUM_VALS = 4;  
    int testGrades[NUM_VALS];           
    int i = 0;                         
    int sumExtra = -9999; // Initialize to 0 before your for loop

testGrades[0] = 101;
testGrades[1] = 83;
testGrades[2] = 107;
testGrades[3] = 90;

// STUDENT CODE GOES HERE


return 0;
}
```

So far all I have is:

```
for (i=0;i<NUM_VALS;++i) {
      if (testGrades[i] > 100) {
         sumExtra = testGrades[i] - 100;
      }
   }
```

I dont know how to find the sum of the array of the values over 100.

Comment: You're close - you just need to initialise sumExtra to 0 before the loop, and change the line inside your loop so that it accumulates.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, initialise `sumExtra` to 0. Then just change:

```
sumExtra = testGrades[i] - 100;
```

to

```
sumExtra += testGrades[i] - 100;
```

because the `sumExtra` for a particular index `i` is `testGrades[i]-100`, and you want to find the total of the `sumExtra`, and hence keeping adding this to the `sumExtra` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the if statement that checks if the test score is above 100. Here is the code that works:

```
    sumExtra = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
      if (testGrades[i] >= 101) {
      sumExtra += (testGrades[i] - 100);
      }
    }
    cout << "sumExtra: " << sumExtra << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize to 0 before your for loop
int sumExtra = 0;

```
sumExtra = testGrades[i]-100;

sumExtra += testGrades[i]-100;
```